# "Error: not opened" when trying to install Meteorite packages

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Meteorite installs great (I have to use `sudo -H npm install -g meteorite` as Meteorite's install instructions recommend), and I can then use it to install standard Meteor packages in my projects, e.g. `mrt add jquery`. But if I try to install any packages from Atmosphere, e.g. `mrt add router` or `mrt add font-awesome`, I get this output:

```
Installing Meteor

  branch: https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git#master

Installing smart packages


/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:175
   else throw new Error('not opened');
           ^
Error: not opened
    at WebSocket.send (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:175:16)
    at DDPClient._send (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/lib/ddp-client.js:77:15)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/lib/ddp-client.js:49:10)
    at WebSocket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at WebSocket.establishConnection (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:576:8)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/ddp/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:488:25)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:175:14)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at CleartextStream.socketOnData (http.js:1587:11)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:477:10)
```

`mrt run` works properly though! I'm on Meteor v0.6.3.1 and Meteorite v0.5.1. Would appreciate any ideas, thanks!

Comment: I also see this error.

Ubuntu 13.04
Node.js 0.10.8

Comment: When you add atmosphere packages with `mrt` it stores a local copy of the package under your `~/.meteorite` directory. Since you installed `npm` and `meteorite` as root, but you are running `mrt` with a user account, could this just be a file permission issue? (i.e. it can't actually write the contents of the router package to `~/.meteorite/packages/router`)

Comment: supposedly running `sudo -H npm install -g meteorite` prevents this problem. I've run `mtr uninstall; mtr uninstall --system; rm -rf ~/.npm` which removes ~/.meteorite and none of that has worked. -- I've `rm -rf ~/.meteorite` just now based on your suggestion and tried again to no avail.

Comment: looks like tls isn't supported. changing `meteoriteArgs.repoPort = meteoriteArgs.repoPort || 443;` to use port 80 in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/atmosphere.js works around it.

Comment: @jason your fix seems to work. Does this break anything if I leave it as 80 instead of 443? I would assume so.

Comment: TLS isn't supported by what? @jason can you open a bug against Meteorite explaining what you think the problem is?

Comment: @KellyCopley I doubt it breaks anything, but requests to atmosphere are now unencrypted.

Comment: @TomColeman https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/issues/135

Comment: @jason, switching it to port 80 worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: For the record you can just run `mrt --repoPort=80` rather than having to mess with the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your node version.

As of today (May 26, 2013), I can replicate this error perfectly (I get the same error message) when I use node v0.10.8.

However, with node node-v0.9.9 the **mrt add** command works.

The other parts of my environment are:

1. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64
2. mrt --version

   Meteorite version 0.5.1

Comment: Thanks, looks like it is indeed a problem related to node 0.10.8. More discussion here: https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/issues/135

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue specifically with Node 0.10.8
https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/issues/135

I was able to fix the issue by first removing node using these instructions. One exception is I had issues using nvm to install node so I used a package instead:
[How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

You'll find links to download installer package for the 0.10.7 version of node for all os' here:
http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/05/17/node-v0-10-7-stable/

After the install do a node -v to check the version. If it doesn't look right try a restart. I had to reboot in order to get mine happy for some reason.

If you continue to have issues after reinstalling node then try removing and reinstalling meteorite and meteor. Hope this helps someone having the same issue.